# Python index() method not returning positions as expected

Tags: python

Get one string of user and print even chars index

```
text = input('Enter a text : ')`  



#For example : Try javadzamani as a string and see the result

#print(f'original string is : {text}')

for item in text :
    x = text.index(item)
    if x % 2 == 0 :
       print(item)
    else :
        pass
```

Comment: `index()` always gives only first index. You would have to use `index(item, start_position)` to get next indexes. But preffered method is `for index, char in enumerate(text):`

Comment: `text.index(item)` is only returning the index of the *first* instance of that character in your string.  Instead try something like `for idx in range(len(text))` or `for idx, char in enumerate(text)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments have correctly pointed out the problem with your code is the use of index(). A simpler way to do this would be:

```
text = input('Enter a text : ')

for index in range(len(text)):
    if(index % 2 != 0):
        print(text [index])
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

`index()` gives only first index.

You would have to use `index(item, start_position)` to get next indexes.

But preferred method is to use `enumerate()`

```
for index, char in enumerate(text):
    if index % 2 == 0:
       print(char)
```

You can also use `slice` like `[0::2]` to get chars with even indexes

```
for char in text[0::2]:
    print(char)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try slicing

```
print(text[::2])
```

Details: [[] (slicing)](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).